# How to setup MCR_CACHE_ROOT in Windows

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-deployment

I know this may be an easy question but How can I setup MCR_CACHE_ROOT in Windows? Can you provide me with the detailed steps. And where should I point the path to MCR_CACHE_ROOT to speed up my compiled application startup time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 7, you set it as an environment variable as follows:

1. Click **Start** then right-click on **Computer**  and choose **Properties** from the menu.
2. In the **System** window, click **Advanced system settings** in the left panel.
3. In the **System properties** dialog, select the **Advanced** tab and click the **Environment variables** button.
4. To add for all users, click **New** under the **System variables** window.

For Windows XP it's very similar [and is described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).

Then you can enter `MCR_CACHE_ROOT` as the variable name, and the required path to variable value. Ok everything and it's done.

You can set the path wherever you like, but it's probably better to create a folder e.g. `C:\MATLAB Cache` and set it there.

Comment: Thanks.How can I setting the path to an empty folder speed up my compiled application?Do I have to do something else after seeting the MCR_CACHE_ROOT in my program?

Comment: If possbile can you go through this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432630/how-to-initialize-and-load-mcr

Comment: Empty folder is fine it will cache files there for reuse.

Comment: I ran my console application and checked the folder but it still empty.Why is this?

Comment: Better to ask a new question, then this answer will be useful to others looking for your first point. You can link back to this question and your other one if necessary.

Comment: Okay thanks I have posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433069/mcr-cache-root-path-empty-after-running-the-console-application