# MCR_CACHE_ROOT path empty after running the console application

Tags: visual-c++, console-application, matlab-deployment

I set the MCR_CACHE_ROOT to a folder C:\MATLAB_cache to speed up my compiled application. Using the linke below

[How to setup MCR_CACHE_ROOT in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432673/how-to-setup-mcr-cache-root-in-windows)

But after I ran the console application calling it from PHP the folder is still empty.Why is it? Should I add anything in my console application or php code after setting up the MCR_CACHE_ROOT? I am working on Windows 7-64bit. The console application is C++ Win32 console application.

I deployed a c++ shared library using deploytool in MATLAB and the ctf archive is embedded in the application is it because of this?

Comment: Some applications only read environment variables on first start - does MCR leave a process running? (I don't know) - it might be worth rebooting and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks yes now there is something in the folder after rebeooting but the speed of the compiled application is still the same.

Comment: It seems like it is not re-using the file because each time the console application runs the folder is replaced. How can I make it re-use it?